# Devexpress move file from explorer into TreeList

Tags: c#, devexpress

I'm trying to drag & drop files into my `TreeList`. I'm able to move files/folders which are inside the `TreeList`, but I also want to drag files from Windows Explorer into the folders of my `TreeList`. The `dragdrop` event of the `treeList` is triggered but both nodes (dragged and target) are null. `e.Data` is not null for both nodes, `e.Data` is a `DataObject`. Maybe there's something wrong with the conversion to `TreeList` nodes, but this event works for drag & drop insde the `TreeList`. How can I solve the nodes problem?

This is the code snippet where the problem occurs:

```
     private void treeList1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {

        var draggedNode = e.Data.GetData(typeof(TreeListNode)) as TreeListNode; //null        
        var targetNode = Tree.ViewInfo.GetHitTest(Tree.PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y))).Node; // null

        if (targetNode == null) return;

        if (draggedNode != null)
        {
            if (targetNode[treeListColumn3].ToString() == "File")
            {
                if (targetNode.ParentNode == draggedNode.ParentNode)
                    return;
                MoveInFolder(draggedNode, targetNode.ParentNode);
            }
            else
            {
                MoveInFolder(draggedNode, targetNode);
            }
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;
        }
        else
        {
            string[] files = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);

            if (files == null) return;

            //Do something with your TreeList
            var nodeTarget = Tree.ViewInfo.GetHitTest(Tree.PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y))).Node;
            TreeListNode node;
            FileInfo fi;
            foreach (string s in files)
            {

                fi = new FileInfo(s);
                node = Tree.AppendNode(new object[] { s, fi.Name, "File", fi.Length, fi }, nodeTarget);
                node.HasChildren = false;
                MoveInFolder(node, nodeTarget);
            }
        }
```

**EDIT** I editted my code to the code which works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you drag files from Windows Explorer you cannot convert it to `TreeListNode` object because you are draging object of another type. You can only get the array of your files by using `DataFormats.FileDrop` as parameter for `e.Data.GetData` method and create/move/delete nodes in your `TreeList` according to files that you droped to it:

```
private void treeList1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    var draggedNode = e.Data.GetData(typeof(TreeListNode)) as TreeListNode; //null        
    var targetNode = Tree.ViewInfo.GetHitTest(Tree.PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y))).Node; // null

    if (targetNode == null) return;

    if (draggedNode != null)
    {
        if (targetNode[treeListColumn3].ToString() == "File")
        {
            if (targetNode.ParentNode == draggedNode.ParentNode)
                return;
            MoveInFolder(draggedNode, targetNode.ParentNode);
        }
        else
        {
            MoveInFolder(draggedNode, targetNode);
        }
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;            
    }
    else
    {
        string[] files = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);

        if (files == null) return;

        //Do something with your TreeList
    }
}
```

Comment: How do I add the file(s) to my treelist if the files array is not null?

Comment: @Sybren You can use [`TreeList.AppendNode`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/DevExpressXtraTreeListTreeList_AppendNodetopic2297) method.

Comment: I found a solution you can check my opening post if u want. I will mark ur answer as accepted because u put me on the right track, thanks for your help. Maybe you can find improvements on the code I added or is it okay?

Comment: @Sybren There are no reason to use `nodeTarget` variable in your code. You can use your `targetNode` variable instead.